# Java Pattern for Classes Inheriting Static Block

Tags: java, oop, static-block

Thanks in advance for the help!

I have a few classes that need to all include the same static block, like:

```java
public class Class1 {
    static {
        changeState();
    }

    ...
}

public class Class2 {
    static {
        changeState();
    }

    ...
}
```

I currently have an abstract class that only includes the mentioned static block, and the others classes all extend the abstract class like:

```java
public abstract class WithChangeState {
    static {
        changeState();
    }
}

public class Class1 extends WithChangeState {    
    ...
}

public class Class2 extends WithChangeState {
    ...
}
```

This doesn't "feel" like the right pattern. Are there other more elegant or correct ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Create a utility class with a static method in it and access it using Classname. Good example in Java API is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html class.

Comment: You've done it. You wanted to inherit a static block, you're inheriting a static block. What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, what I ended up doing was:

```java
// utility class with a static method
public abstract class ChangeState {
    public static void initialize() {
        changeState();
    }
}

// access it using Classname
public class Class1 {    
    static {
        ChangeState.initialize();
    }
    ...
}

// access it using Classname
public class Class2 {
    static {
        ChangeState.initialize();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hard to see the point of that. What improvement do you think it represents over what you had in your question?

Comment: Which is the use case scenario you're trying to face with this solution? I mean, the `static` method `initialize` seems to me like a Constructor, isn't it? So, why don't you use basic OOP, instead of esoteric `static` methods?

Comment: I want to install a security provider in multiple library classes. Some of which already extend abstract classes. I want access to security providers in the implementations.